# Can we load external Javascript inside a specific function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am curious to know that if it is possible to load some external javascript code from a url to some function. Suppose we are having a function like this,

```
function example(){
var x = 10;
alert(x);
console.log(x);
};
```

Here in the above function I want to call "console.log(x)" form some external script. So what should I write for that (I know the way I have written doesn't work, but its for understanding only),

```
function example(){
var x = 10;
alert(x);
<script src="https://example.com/console.js"></script>
};
```

Where "https://example.com/console.js" url contains the external javascript code of "console.log(x);"
This example I have given is very simple for understanding. My function is very complex and I am just wondering if I can call small codes insides my big overall function from external javascript from url. Because if we can do it then updating large functions will be very easy as we need to update only that specific section at the cdn url.

Comment: Sounds like you want modules. Do you prefer using build tools or standard browser code?

Comment: I just want to call some javascript code inside a simple javascript function from external url.

Answer (score 1):

If your environment support ES6 modules,

```
function example () {
   import(‘console.js’).then((module)) => {
         # use you module here
   });
 };
```

It’s limit to the same origin in browser though, so console.js and the JavaScript file containing example() need to be on the same url.

Comment: Can I use module by hosting my .js file on github and hosting my page on blogger? Where can I read more about it Sir?

Comment: @Instanano no you can’t, the files have to be on the same url.

Comment: So there is no way to do it without same url or even without using modules?

Comment: There probably some hacks use “eval” to load external js string and call “eval” but it’s highly discouraged because security reasons.

Comment: Its okay can you please give me some live example for "eval"? Some basic on how to use it like in the above exam I have given